# Why does my soapui testcase fail after installing new soapui version (5.3.0 -> 5.4.0)

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertion

[image: groovy assertion fail]

Hey there, i have SOAPUI testcases written in groovy. The tests were fine with 5.3.0 (on a Linux machine), before i installed the latest version of SOAPUI (5.4.0, on a Windows 10 machine). With the new version i get an assertion fail. It seems an array is created and put into an array at index 0. So that names.contains("username") fails.

I dont understand why the test fails after installing the new version of SOAPUI.

Does anybody have clue whats goin on here? 
And does anybody have a download for version 5.3.0, so i can test again with that version?

best regards

Comment: could you provide the response example of your service?

Comment: on screenshot you can see that `names` variable is list of list of names, but assertion expects list of names. probably the response has changed?

Comment: here is the response example  `{
   "username": "emma",
   "domain": "user.example.net",
   "token": "eyJiwiaHIiLCJodSIsImVuIiwiaXQiLCJtdCIsIm5sIiwibm8iLCJwbCIs",
   "firstName": "emma",
   "lastName": "watson",
   "locale": "de",
   "defaultLanguage": "en",
   "orgaStructureId": 1015157000001,
   "samlToken": null
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I confirm that the following code fails in soapui 5.4.0:**

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
def jsonData = '''
{ "aaa":1, "bbb":2 }
'''

def json = new JSONObject(jsonData)
def names = json.names().iterator().toList()

assert names.contains("aaa")
log.info "SUCCESS!!!"
```

with error:

```
Assertion failed: assert names.contains("aaa") | | | false [["aaa","bbb"]] error at line: 9
```

---

**The problem:**

the soapui 5.4.0 contains very old library for `org.json` package: `json-20090211.jar`

other versions: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

---

**workarounds**

1. replace `json-20090211.jar` in the `lib` folder of soapui with [newer version](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20171018/json-20171018.jar). but not sure how this will affect soapui itself.
2. rewrite your code with groovy-based json parser:

---

```
def jsonData = '''
{ "aaa":1, "bbb":2 }
'''

def json = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonData)
def names = json.keySet()

assert names.contains("aaa")
log.info "SUCCESS!!!"
```

Comment: replacing json-20090211.jar in the lib folder of soapui with newer version json-20171018.jar solved the problem. thank you.